# Where did about:blank get its name from?

Tags: browser

All browsers I tested support `about:blank` as a URL for an empty page. I understand the `blank`, but where comes the `about` from?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> about: is an internal URI scheme (also
>   known as a "URL scheme" or,
>   erroneously, "protocol") in various
>   web browsers to display certain
>   built-in functions. It is not an
>   officially registered scheme, and has
>   no standard syntax.
>
> In early versions of Netscape, any
>   address beginning about: which wasn't
>   recognised as a built-in command would
>   simply result in the text after the
>   colon being displayed. Similarly, in
>   early versions of Internet Explorer,
>   about: followed by a string of HTML
>   (e.g. about:*hello world*)
>   would render that string as though it
>   was the source of the page - thus
>   providing a similar (though more
>   limited) facility to the data: URI
>   scheme defined by RFC 2397. Still
>   other versions of Netscape would
>   return various phrases in response to
>   an unknown about: address, including
>   "Whatchew talkin' 'bout, Willis?" (a
>   catch phrase from the TV show
>   Diff'rent Strokes) or "Homey don't
>   play dat!" (from a recurring skit on
>   the TV show In Living Color).
>
> The most commonly implemented about:
>   URIs are about:blank, which displays a
>   blank HTML document, and simply
>   about:, which may display information
>   about the browser. Opera uses URIs
>   beginning with opera: for similar
>   purposes, and many about: URIs will be
>   translated into an appropriate opera:
>   URI if entered; an exception is
>   about:blank, which is not translated.

[Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/About:_URI_scheme)

Comment: Before the late 90's, all you had was protocols, so 'erroneously, "protocol"' is a bit harsh, considering the protocols came first and that portion of the URI has since been co-opted to fulfill multiple purposes.

Answer (score 2):

It's a generic name for the browser's about pages. I believe netscape was the first to use them, and they've caught on since then. A more technical explanation would be that `about:` is the **protocol**, and tells the browser what it's looking for is built in to the browser, no DNS or file requests necessary. Thusly, `about:blank` was used because `about:` was already programmed in, and less complexity means less bugs, and fewer potential security holes.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a shorthand for "a browser page that isn't connecting to the anything (externally)". See also about:config, about:cache, about:plugins. Full list [here on SU](https://superuser.com/questions/38274/list-of-firefoxs-about-pages/38277#38277)

Just noticed that SU's search allows about:config!